# Tomcat resources not resolving correctly

Tags: tomcat, hostname, tomcat6, fqdn

I'm trying to deploy [MITRE's OpenID Connect Java Spring Server](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server) using Tomcat. My server's FQDN is `park.muller.io`.

I've compiled the MITRE server and placed the .war file into the Tomcat `webapps` directory. When I visit [park.muller.io:8080/openid-connect-server-webapp](http://park.muller.io:8080/openid-connect-server-webapp/), I see the landing page contents... but none of the images or stylesheets resolve. Upon further inspection, the `src` attribute for the images is a relative URL, but when I right-click on the image and try to view it, it resolves the host to `localhost:8080`. I've confirmed this behavior on my desktop and on my tablet, so it's not an `/etc/hosts` issue as I first suspected (I used to have `park.muller.io` resolve to my home address, but it doesn't do that anymore.)

On `park`, if I run `hostname -f`, it returns `park.muller.io` as expected. This is because I've declared this in `/etc/hosts` in an effort to fix the problem on my own.

I'm completely baffled; this makes ZERO sense to me. What's making the relative links resolve to `localhost`, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `issuer` value inside the `server-config.xml` configuration file and set it to the final deployment path. This is mentioned in the server configuration documentation but could probably be worded more clearly:

https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/wiki/Server-configuration

Essentially, the Java servlet doesn't make it easy to consistently get the current URL, and even then it will be wrong if you host behind a proxy (such as Tomcat behind Apache using mod_ajp). As such, we decided to just have it be a configuration value in the MITREid Connect server project.